# How to make my Arithmetic Class Modular c# CLI Program

Tags: c#, variables, console, console-application, modularity

**Background:**

Hey guys, I'm studying a course in Software Design right now and I'm pretty confused over this.

I decided to write a program so I could go over the basics of class:class interaction, and I have two classes right now, an Arithmetic Class which contains some very simple methods such as `multiply()`, `addition()` etc.

and my main class which contains a CLI menu via a case statement.

What I'm trying to do is make my Arithmetic class modular.

My `ResultGen()` and `randomNumberGen()` methods contain `Console.WriteLine` and if possible, I don't want this Arithmetic class to have to rely on the Console Class being present (As I want to use this Arithmetic class with a GUI WPF program soon)

**My question is,**

how do I take the `month` and the `year` variables from my `randomNumberGen()` method over to my main `Program()` class so I can format those there, and how do I take the `result` variable from `ResultGen()` over too?

Preferably I'd like to use parameters or getters and setters to fulfil this problem rather than returns.

```
    public int ResultGen()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result is equal to: " + result + ".");
        return result;
    }

    public void randomNumberGen()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        month = rnd.Next(1, 11); // creates a number between 1 and 12
        year = rnd.Next(1, 21); // creates a number between 1 and 51
        Console.WriteLine("Month: " + month);
        Console.WriteLine("Year:  " + year);
    }
```

Here's my main program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProgramMenu();
    }

    static void ProgramMenu()
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
        Arithmetic math = new Arithmetic();
        math.randomNumberGen();
        Console.WriteLine("Press '1' for addition or '2' for multiplication, press '3 'to generate results");
        do
        {
            cki = Console.ReadKey(false); // show the key as you read it
            switch (cki.KeyChar.ToString())
            {
                case "1":
                {
                    math.addition();
                    math.ResultGen();
                    break;
                }
                case "2":
                {
                    math.multipy();
                    math.ResultGen(); 
                    break;
                }
                case "3":
                {
                    math.randomNumberGen();
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help you guys can give, but please keep in mind that I am a novice programmer only trying to understand basic practices.

If I tried to do this, I'd probably use a toString() method and I've tried that and failed.

Comment: Where is your main program?

Comment: added it to the main comment.

Comment: Simply create a instance var on class level. That can be used to communicate between main and class methods.

Comment: So I make the variable, for instance "year" in my program class and I can send that to my Arithmetic class?

How?

Comment: Actually I'm no Cxx programmer, but if you declare an instance variable (you should know what that is) you can set and get that in your class instance. Go have a read about it.

Comment: That's why I came here, to ask for an explanation in layman terms. Maybe I just shouldn't have bothered.

If necessary I'll go read the c# tutorial but yeah, I'd rather get a human response.

I know what instance variables are, and I know what getters and setters are, I'm just not sure how to utilize them in my code.

Comment: Then just wait if someone takes care. I could only show it theoretically (or in some other language), not in concrete Cxx code. That would not help you.

Comment: FYI - `rnd.Next(1, 11);` will return a random number between 1 and 10. The 11 is an exclusive upper bound.

Comment: I know that Enigmativity, thanks though. (I forgot to edit the comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Tuples

For the first method just remove the `Console.WriteLine` call and do it in your application that is handling output.

For the second one you need to return both variables in this case would suggest returning a Tuple.

Change the return type of your randomNumberGen to `Tuple<int,int>` the type for a two tuple with both members' types being ints, so your method signature should be

```
public Tuple<int,int> randomNumberGen()
```

You should create the tuple from the two variables (month and year), again a few ways to do this, easiest using the start `Tuple.Create`

So your return statement should look like this `return Tuple.Create(month,year)`

At the callers end to remove the variables you can call the `Item1` property for the first, and `Item2` property for the second.

your method should look like this

```
public Tuple<int,int> RandomNumberGen()
{

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int month = rnd.Next(1, 11); // creates a number between 1 and 12
    int year = rnd.Next(1, 21); // creates a number between 1 and 51

    return Tuple.Create(month,year);

}
```

and in your main

```
    var result = math.randomNumberGen();
    var month = result.Item1;
    var year = result.Item2;
```

Now you can do with month and year whatever you'd like.

***Design Notes***

Know this wasn't part of your question but just as an FYI normally convention for naming public facing members in C# is upper camel case, locals are lower camel case

### Properties ( doesn't make sense in this case )

You can set properties in any context with visibility to that properties setter, that is the property, in this case **doing it this way makes no sense**:

in your class

```
public int Month{ get; private set;} 
public int Year { get; private set; }

public void RandomNumberGen()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Month = rnd.Next(1, 11); // creates a number between 1 and 12
    Year = rnd.Next(1, 21); // creates a number between 1 and 51

}
```

And in your main

```
var custGenVarName = new Arithmetic();
custGenVarName.RandomNumberGen();
int month = custGenVarName.Month;
int year = custGenVarName.Year;
```

in this case that doesn't make sense, as a calculation result should not live in the object that is meant to do calculation, should do the calculation and return to the caller

Comment: Tuple is new to me but it's interesting, however, if I didn't use tuple, are there any other ways I could do this?

Comment: @JohnnyMccrum, yes there are more ways, but this does what you asked, gets both of the variables out to the caller of the method, if you have more specific requirements please put them in the question and I will answer it as best I can

Comment: For instance, could I use Parameters or Getters and setters to get those variables instead of returns?

Comment: @JohnnyMccrum yes you could, but really what you are doing is calculating a value for consumption, saving the value in a member variable makes no sense because the value should not logically belong to the object.